# Если ли альтернативной метод onBackPressed для TabActivity

Tags: android

Если ли альтернативной метод `onBackPressed` для `TabActivity`?

нужно `tabActivity` сделать диалоговое окно для кнопки `Back`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте следующий код чайлдам своей TabActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
}
```

Теперь вы можете использовать onBackPressed у своей TabActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Called by children
}
```

По-умолчанию, потомки активити перехватывают событие и оно не доходит до TabActivity.

*Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796050/key-events-in-tabactivities*